# Existe grandes difrenças na "gravação binária" de um ficheiro, ao entrar com listas ou dicionários?

Tags: c#, estrutura-de-dados, dicionário, serialização, desserialização

Estou a desenvolver um projeto na linguagem `C#` em que necessito de recorrer a ficheiros para guardar os dados que circulam nas estruturas de dados.

Acontece que eu tinha o projeto todo mal elaborado, não estava a programar por camadas. Eu anteriormente estava a recorrer a Listas (estrutura de dados) e para gravar os Dados os metodos que abaixo estão apresentados trabalhavam perfeitamente

```
 public static bool GravaCarrosEstacionados(string filename,Dictionary<string,Park> carros)
        {

            try
              {
                 Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create);
                 BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
                 bin.Serialize(stream, carros);
                 stream.Close();
                 return true;
              }
              catch (IOException e)   
              {
                  Console.Write("ERRO:" + e.Message);
                  return false;
              }
        }


 public static bool CarregarCarrosEstacionados(string fileName,string nomeP)
        {
            if (File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                try
                {
                    Stream stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open);
                    BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
                    parques = (Dictionary<string,Park>)bin.Deserialize(stream);
                    stream.Close();

                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Park> x in parques)
                    {
                        if (parques.ContainsKey(nomeP))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Carro {0}", x.Value.Carro.Marca);
                            Console.WriteLine("Modelo {0}", x.Value.Carro.Modelo);
                            Console.WriteLine("Matricula {0}", x.Value.Carro.Matricula);


                        }

                    }

                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    Console.Write("ERRO:" + e.Message);
                    return false;
                }


            }
            return true;

        }
```

Obviamente que aplicava listas em vez de dicionários durante o `"serialize"` e o `"Deserialize"`. Agora com o dicionário ao adicionar por exemplo um carro ao sistema nem consigo sequer gravar o ficheiro.

O que poderá estar a acontecer de diferente?

Comment: Quais são os erros que ocorrem?

Comment: Aprecebo-me que o ficheiro não é gravado quando o método GravaCarrosEstacionados(string filename,Dictionary<string,Park> carros) é chamado acima (noutro metodo)

Comment: Não sei se esta adaptação está correcta, dai a minha duvida neste algoritmo

Comment: Com listas o mesmo metodo trabalhou perfeitamente